# post id of td after click using jquery ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/subodhkachare/wzjoptnL/)I have following jquery ajax,which includes page into div after click on cells:

```
$(function () {
    $('.yo').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $('#prodajx').val();
        var value1 = $('#cityajx').val();
        var value2 = $('#regionajx').val();
        $.post('demo_link_table_static.php', {value: value, value1: value1, value2: value2}, function (data) {
            $("#search_results").html(data);

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now I want `id` of td in ajax post method... How can I get `id` of `td` (after click) and post it to another page? Thank you.

Comment: `$(this)[0].id` or `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: var id = $(this).attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

```
var id_current = $(this).attr('id');  

var id_0 = $('#prodajx').attr('id');
var id_1 = $('#cityajx').attr('id');
var id_2 = $('#regionajx').attr('id');
```

Comment: OP wants the id of the clicked td. The id of the class yo element clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('.yo').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $('#prodajx').val();
        var value1 = $('#cityajx').val();
        var value2 = $('#regionajx').val();
        var id_td = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
                url: "demo_link_table_static.php",
                type: "POST",
                data : "id_td="+id_td+"&value="+value+"&value1="+value1+"&value2="+value2,
                success:function(data){
                    $("#search_results").html(data);
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: have you put id attribute on your td?